# facebook open graph count shares using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As from Facebook documentation I can get the count of shares for a web page calling the following url https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.it, the returned data are the following:

```
{
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 636734
   },
   "og_object": {
      "id": "389545309239",
      "title": "Google",
      "type": "website",
      "updated_time": "2017-06-08T10:05:50+0000"
   },
   "id": "http://www.google.it"
}
```

I want to get the same data using the PHP SDK using the following code:

```
//require the Facebook PHP SDK

$client_id="my app id";
$client_secret="my secret key";
$default_access_token = file_get_contents( "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&grant_type=client_credentials");

$OGResponse = new Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken($default_access_token);

$access_token = json_decode($OGResponse)->access_token;

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $client_id, // Replace {app-id} with your app id
    'app_secret' => $client_secret,
    'default_access_token' => $access_token,
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$request = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest(
    $fb->getApp(),
    $access_token,
    'GET',
    '/',
    array(
        'id' => 'http://www.google.it',
    )
);

$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);

//$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Accessing the $graphObject I can retrieve the same data except the ones in "share" key, that are what I'm interested.

If I use the GRAPH API Explorer, I get the same info using the PHP SDK:

```
{
  "og_object": {
  "id": "389545309239",
  "title": "Google",
  "type": "website",
  "updated_time": "2017-06-08T10:05:50+0000"
},
"id": "http://www.google.it"
}
```

Is there any way to get the "shares" using the PHP SDK?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this 
[graph api explorer v2.8](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.it%26fields%3Dshare%2Cog_object&version=v2.8)

but you cannot get share field with graph api v2.9 because share field is deprecated for versions v2.9 and higher,or you can use `engagement` field like this [graph api explorer v2.9](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.it%26fields%3Dengagement%2Cog_object&version=v2.9)

for PHP SDK:

```
$request = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest(
    $fb->getApp(),
    $access_token,
    'GET',
    '/',
    array(
        'id'     => 'http://www.google.it',
        'fields' => 'engagement,og_object',
    )
);
```

then you will get something like this

```
{
  "engagement": {
    "reaction_count": 207037,
    "comment_count": 125335,
    "share_count": 304362,
    "comment_plugin_count": 0
  },
  "og_object": {
    "id": "389545309239",
    "title": "Google",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2017-06-08T15:58:56+0000"
  },
  "id": "http://www.google.it"
}
```

Comment: I'm recieving an object instead a json. Also, the object has no any information about the Graph Api Explorer returns. Could you help me saying me why? Thanks a lot.